# How to delete XCode personal team provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I created a free team provisioning profile, then I developed my app using it and then I decided to create a paid account to distribute my app.

When I try to change the "Team" in the App's settings from the (Free) team to the (Agent) team, it generates the following error:

[image: provisioning profiles error]

When I click "Fix Issue", I get the following error:

An App ID with Identifier '...' is not available. Please enter a different string.

I figured this is because the App ID is already used in the provisioning profile associated with the (Free) team. So I opened XCode -> Preferences -> Accounts, Selected my (Free) team and pressed "View Details". I saw a list of provisioning profiles. I selected all of them and chose "Move To Trash". It still did not remove any of them from the list. It just placed a button labeled "Download" next to each of them. I don't know where else are these profiles stored given that my Free account is not associated with a Member Center account.

So, I just ignored this and tried to press "Fix Issue" again, but I still got the same error. Any ideas how to fix this?

One last bit of info: Both of the teams (Free & Agent) are under the same account.

Other things I tried:

- Tried to find a way to delete my (Free) team. There's no delete button that I can find.
- Tried to delete the account and recreate it. Can't do that. The minus button is disabled; I guess that's because it's the only account in the list.

Any help is appreciated.